# preload images using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image-preloader

I got this snippet of code following a [tutorial comment](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-definitive-guide-to-creating-a-practical-jquery-plugin/) (by James) on Nettuts and I would like to implement it.

The tutorial method of preloading images is long winded but I liked James' shortened version of this, however, I have tried implementing this and I am not getting it right.

It seems I would need to set up my array first, the loop through that array which then creates the image objects and loads them. Yet, when I check my Firebug, I am not seeing any images load into the cache.

```
$(function(){
      var imgArray = ['bghome01.jpg', 'bghome02.jpg', 'bghome03.jpg'];
        $.preload = function (imgArray) {
            $.each(imgArray, function () {
                alert(imgArray);
                (new Image()).src = 'Images/' + this;
            });
        };
    });
```

I'd appreciate the help!

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Right here, you're *defining* a function, but not *calling* it:

```
$.preload = function (imgArray) {
```

If you just want to load the images, you can slim it down to this:

```
$(function(){
  var imgArray = ['bghome01.jpg', 'bghome02.jpg', 'bghome03.jpg'];
  $.each(imgArray, function () {
    (new Image()).src = 'Images/' + this;
  });
});
```

Or, you can do it with your original method, the function definition can be in an external file, but in the page you need to call it, like this:

```
var imgArray = ['bghome01.jpg', 'bghome02.jpg', 'bghome03.jpg'];
$.preload(imgArray);
```

I think the confusion here comes from `imgArray` being the name for the array *and* the parameter, but these are 2 separate things, it might be less confusing if you gave the parameter to `$.preload` a different name.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you don't keep the image objects around, so the garbage collection might throw them away before the image can be loaded.

See this article for some code: http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript

Note that jQuery doesn't do any magic; it's all JavaScript in the end, so something must be wrong with your code. So if keeping the image objects alive doesn't help, maybe [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5214317.html) will point you in the right direction.

Comment: The first article creates nodes in the DOM, the second seems to assume nothing will get garbage collected. I think you're right though, the OP should probably just put the image array in the top level context somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

If *I* where a browser i would only load images that are on the page, so I suspect his happens because you never add the images to the DOM. Try setting creating a new img-tag with `style="visibility:hidden"` an add it to the DOM.

Comment: Hi Martin,

Reading through that tutorial on Nettuts, it is exactly what the guy as doing - injecting the images into the page and hiding them. If you read further down the tut, in the comments, James (not me) makes a comment about loading the images in a different way. Are you suggesting that there is no way of loading the images into cache without loading it into the DOM?

Thanks ;)

Comment: I must admit I didn't do any research on this. But I could imagine, that a intelligent browser won't load any image, that are not "on" the page. Your Firefox obviously does it this way...

Comment: -1 Image preloading is a standard trick to speed up page load times. It is possible and you don't need to add the image to the DOM.